# Drupal loading hierarchy

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I want to know more about drupal loading hierarchy process: what is "coming" before what.
For example, is block being rendered before the node ? is the template.php file is being rendered before any tpl ?
If anyone can tell me please the full list/treeview about those template files order when they are being rendered.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

http://drupal.org/node/173880
here imho is a good article about how rendering is processed